# Error usando PHPMailer (500 Internal Server Error) Timeout

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy intentando usar la librería **PHPMailer** con una instalacón manual (tal y como lo indican en la [documentación](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading)) (No tengo acceso a Composer).

Ahora mismo estoy intentando enviar un correo electrónico de prueba usando el [ejemplo de la documentación](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) (cambiando los datos de ejemplo por los de mi servidor) y resulta que al cargar el archivo, se queda cargando un minuto o poco más y finalmente me muestra el siguiente error (**500 Internal Server Error**):

> **Request Timeout** This request takes too long to process, it is timed
>   out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact
>   administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

Código completo:
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yUXWtHvY)

**Nota 1:** No se genera el archivo error_log (Aunque este está habilitado).
**Nota 2:** Los archivos están icluidos correctamente, ya que cuando no es así (lo he probado) se genera un error fatal y se crea el archivo error_log con el correspondiente error.

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones en la pregunta el mensaje del error log? Es lo más importante para saber cuál es el problema.

Comment: Como he comentado, este problema no me genera ningún archivo de error_log. Lo que dicho sobre que otros problemas si lo hacen es para que sepan que tengo habilitado el error_log. Saludos!

Comment: Perdona, entendí mal esto que decías en la pregunta: *lo he probado) se genera un error fatal y se crea el archivo error_log con el correspondiente error*  ... vamos a ver el pastebin...

Comment: Primera sugerencia, no uses `true` cuando construyes el objeto, ponlo así: `$mail = new PHPMailer();`  ahora si falla deberá generar una excepción o escribir en el log de errores. Revisa...

Comment: @A.Cedano Sigue apareciendo lo mismo después de estar más de un minuto cargando. (Sin generar el archivo error_log)

Comment: Ok. Pon **temporalmente** el modo de debug más hablador a ver si dice algo: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;` Por cierto, ¿ese código es llamado dentro de algún bucle o algo así?

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es probar a poner esta configuración: **`$mail->Timeout =   60; $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;`**

Comment: Ya he encontrado el error. He estado probando muchas cosas, y ha funcionado después de cambiar SMTPSecure de tls a ssl. Muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto. Propongo que redactes una respuesta sobre los pasos que diste para determinar el problema, así podría servir a otros que tengan este inconveniente.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste desactivando el cortafuegos o el antivirus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de probar cambiar varias cosas, he encontrado el problema modificando el SMTPSecure de `tls` a `ssl`, tal y como se muestra en la siguiente línea:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```